Diagnosing faulty bands calculation
Using QE v6.7, I computed the bands structure of CsPbI3 and I am not happy with the results.

The Problem
While performing the nscf calculation I kept getting the error c_bands too many bands are not converged. Going through the source code I saw that this error is triggered when the notconv parameter in PW/src/c_bands.f90 exceeds a certain threshold.
The cell was relaxed. Moreover when performing scf calculations I performed convergence tests on ecut, erho, and k_points.
Attempts at Solution
I also tried changing the diagonalization method to cg but that returned the same problem.
Taking cue from queries by people with similar problems I lowered conv_thr =   1.0000000000d-05 and later made diago_david_ndim = 6. This made the calculation proceed without any error but the band structure is evidently incorrect.
How to Proceed?
My question is what is the standard procedure to diagnose this problem? Should I:

Go back to the scf calculation or persist with the nscf one?
Is the conv_thr reasonable or too low?
Is there any other parameter, e.g. smearing that can be changed to improve the bands output?
Is it possible that the diago_david_ndim need to be changed not only on the nscf input file but also the scf input file?

For Reference
The input files are available on github.
The k-point path is as follows:
K_POINTS {crystal_b}
8
0.0000000000    0.0000000000    0.0000000000 30 !gamma
0.0000000000    0.5000000000    0.0000000000 30 !X
0.5000000000    0.5000000000    0.0000000000 30 !M
0.0000000000    0.0000000000    0.0000000000 30 !gamma
0.5000000000    0.5000000000    0.5000000000 30 !R
0.0000000000    0.5000000000    0.0000000000 0 !X
0.5000000000    0.5000000000    0.5000000000 30 !R
0.5000000000    0.5000000000    0.0000000000 30 !M


we need to see your SCF output and your NSCF input. Just the k point alone is not enough

I've added a link to the github repository in the original post.

That's much better. I'm going to leave this to someone more qualified to help you, but in the meantime, I can make some suggestions. Why are you using PBE PAW pseudopotentials mixed with one PBE US? It would be much less of a headache to figure out if you are doing something correct or not if you use the same type throughout. You are also using a supercell; even the output is complaining that you should not use ibrav=0. Can you use a primitive cell and use the crystal symmetries? Why is it that your k point path has a 0 !X? 0 steps, no wonder it is broken there.

Thank you. I'll try your PP advice. Can you help me with your other suggestion, regarding ibrav=0 since I'd presumed making a supercell was necessary, especially for relaxation calculations. I generated this file using materialscloud so didn't pay much attention to it since I was relaxing the cell. The documentation says you can make ibrav=0 and supply CELL_PARAMETERS.

Oh no, if you can use a primitive cell, you should. It will take much less energy, much less memory and much less time to do a calculation with primitive cell, than with a supercell. You use a supercell when you kinda have no other way out. Of course, there is nothing forcing you to use nice primitive cells, i.e. you can use ibrav=0, but you should use whatever is nice. For example, I often check what other people have stated of a particular structure, and then looked up its space group. QE accepts the space group, so I just import that. Saves me a lot of work!

That's awesome. But is that true for the force and stress in relaxation calculations too? I'm slightly confused how the relaxation is going to carried out since the force on an atom would be an extensive quantity.

That's the beauty of having someone else write the code for you; they have already implemented the correct forces for the primitive cell cases too.
